# Setting up routing in order to GET an entity using different "id"s in WebApi

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

Say for example I have the following model:

```
public class Comment
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long UserId { get; set; }
    public long AccountId { get; set; }
    public long EventId { get; set; }

    public string Body { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
}
```

I already have it set up so that `GET /comments/` returns all comments for your account 
and `GET /comments/123` return the one comment. This is not a problem via default routing.

But I wonder how to be able to have two extra GET endpoints, one being able to return all comments for an `EventId` and the other, all comments for a `UserId`.

Any thoughts would be appreciated!

Comment: I would probably go with action routing, but if you wanted to stay true to rest, I would think that you would do something like a Get on a UserController that returned a User object with a collection of comments on it and a Get on an EventController that returned an Event with a collection of comments also.

Comment: I'm thinking of maybe setting up the following routes: `comments/user/11` and `comments/event/999`

Answer (score 0):

you can alter your routing to look for the method name (the action) :

```
{controller}/{action}/{id}
```

then you can have multiple `GET` methods that will clearly state their intent:

```
GetCommentsForUser();
GetCommentsForEvent();
GetCommentsForAccount();
```

and of course the URL will be

```
/comments/GetCommentsForUser/123
```